# add unbound update and delete button in databound datagridview vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i have a datagridview that is data bound and i want to add update and delete button that will enable to open another form containing the record that needs to be updated. 
The datagrid was something like this one

```
    conn = New MySqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=test"
    Dim sda As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dbDataset As New DataSet
    Dim bsource As New BindingSource

    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "select user_id as 'ID', lname as 'Lastname', fname as 'Firstname' from test.user"
        comm = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
        sda.SelectCommand = comm
        sda.Fill(dbDataset)
        bsource.DataSource = dbDataset
        userDatagridview.DataSource = bsource
        sda.Update(dbDataset)
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Comment: You *can* do that without a button.  Users can edit the date in the DataGridView and it will flow back to the datatable.  Or the user double clicks on the row or the row header and zooom - new form with edit controls - but now you gotta figure out how to update that row and where it is.  Where is that code located?  Form Load maybe?

Comment: You can add them in the designer before its databound.